# Boundedness of inverse in Evans Chapter 6 (why is the sequence bounded in Sobolev spaces?)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Evans says this can be estimate by energy estimates,but this is true if α＜β,what about α≥β,could the estimate be valid again ([screenshot transcribed below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfZmw.png))

> **THEOREM 6** (Boundedness of the inverse). If $\lambda \notin \Sigma$, there exists a constant $C$ such that
>
> $$
> \|u\|_{L^{2}(U)} \leq C\|f\|_{L^{2}(U)} \tag{29}
> $$
> whenever $f \in L^{2}(U)$ and $u \in H_{0}^{1}(U)$ is the unique weak solution of
> $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
> L u=\lambda u+f & \text { in } U \\
> u=0 & \text { on } \partial U
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> The constant $C$ depends only on $\lambda, U$ and the coefficients of $L .$
> This constant will blow up if $\lambda$ approaches an eigenvalue.
>
> *Proof.* If not, there would exist sequences $\left\{f_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset L^{2}(U)$ and $\left\{u_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset$ $H_{0}^{1}(U)$ such that
> $$
> \left\{\begin{aligned}
> L u_{k} &=\lambda u_{k}+f_{k} & & \text { in } U \\
> u_{k} &=0 & & \text { on } \partial U
> \end{aligned}\right.
> $$
> in the weak sense, but
> $$
> \left\|u_{k}\right\|_{L^{2}(U)}>k\left\|f_{k}\right\|_{L^{2}(U)} \quad(k=1, \ldots)
> $$
> As we may with no loss suppose $\left\|u_{k}\right\|_{L^{2}(U)}=1,$ we see $f_{k} \rightarrow 0$ in $L^{2}(U)$. **According to the usual energy estimates the sequence $\left\{u_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded in $H_{0}^{1}(U) .$** Thus...

The energy estimate is below ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qu5S.png)):

THEOREM 2 (Energy estimates). There exist constants $\alpha, \beta>0$ and $\gamma \geq 0$ such that

$$
|B[u, v]| \leq \alpha\|u\|_{H_{0}^{1}(U)}\|v\|_{H_{0}^{1}(U)}\tag{i}
$$
and

$$
\beta\|u\|_{H_{0}^{1}(U)}^{2} \leq B[u, u]+\gamma\|u\|_{L^{2}(U)}^{2}\tag{ii}
$$

Could someone help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please type the important bits with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Sorry,It's my first time to ask questions on this site.parameter α,β are in energy estimate, you can click [2](the second link)

Comment: I have some problem in the following of his proof.Could I edit this problem again?

Comment: you can ask a new question, if you need to type mathematics, please use MathJax and you should read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to increase the chance of getting a good reply

Comment: Thank you!I will ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use (i), (ii) is enough and gives
\begin{align}
 \|u\|_{H^1_0(U)}^2 
&\le \frac1\beta B[u,u] + \frac\gamma\beta \|u\|_{L^2(U)}^2 
\\&= \frac1\beta (u,f)_{L^2(U)} + \frac\gamma\beta\|u\|^2_{L^2(U)} 
\\&\le \frac1\beta\|u\|_{L^2(U)}\|f\|_{L^2(U)}+\frac\gamma\beta\|u\|_{L^2(U)}^2  
\\&=\frac1\beta\|f\|_{L^2(U)}+\frac\gamma\beta
\end{align}
where we used the definition of a weak solution $B[u,v]=(f,v)_{L^2(U)}$ valid for all $v\in H^1_0(U)$ (in particular valid for $v=u$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!This helps me a lot.